# How can I pass the list to the component variable in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, list, components, laravel-blade

How can I pass the list to the component variable? I tried to add elements of a list in `@php` tags like this **, for now,**, in the future, I will fetch this list from the database.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given
```

Component in my blade file looks like this
`resource/views/pricing.blade.php`

```dart
<div>
 @php
   $allowedFeaturesList = ["a","b","c"];
@endphp
   <x-widgets.pricingCard name="Free" allowedFeaturesList="{{$allowedFeaturesList}}"/>
</div>
```

`resources\views\components\widgets\pricingCard.blade.php`

```dart
<div class="card-body p-5">
    <div class="small text-uppercase fw-bold text-muted">{{$name}}</div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-4">
        <!-- Below is how I'm trying to render list -->
        @foreach ($allowedFeaturesList as $item)
        <li class="mb-2">
            <i class="bi bi-check text-primary"></i>
            {{$value}}
        </li>
        @endforeach
      
    </ul>
</div>
```

`app\View\Components\widgets\pricingCard.php`

```dart
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\widgets;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class pricingCard extends Component
{


    public $name;
    public Array $allowedFeaturesList;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name,$price,$booledFeature,$allowedFeaturesList,$restrictedFeaturesList,)
    {
        $this->name= $name;
        $this->allowedFeaturesList= $allowedFeaturesList;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.widgets.pricingCard');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. On your view component tag

   ```
   <x-widgets.pricingCard name="Free" allowedFeaturesList="{!! json_encode($allowedFeaturesList) !!}}"/>
   ```
2. On pricingCard.php file

   ```
   {
      $this->name= $name;
      $this->allowedFeaturesList= json_decode($allowedFeaturesList);
   }
   ```